# Kable, Flextable, Huxtable to HTML: force the display of cell contents on a single line

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, kable, flextable

I want the contents of my cells to be displayed in a single line. I'm using Rmarkdown to HTML.
But no matter which package I use (`Kable`, `Flextable`, `Huxtable`), the column width specification is ignored and a line break is introduced, which makes the very ugly and unreadable results.
In HTML, with a drop-down box, the total width shouldn't be a problem. I just want the results to be readable.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(flextable)

table = as.data.frame(matrix(rep("value [value1 - value2]",20), ncol = 10))

kbl(table) %>%
  kable_paper() %>%column_spec(1:ncol(table), width = "3.5cm", bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE)%>%
  scroll_box(width = "1000px", height = "500px")

tb = flextable(table)%>% flextable::width(width = 10)
knit_print(tb)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With flextable, this code forces (note the usage of `autofit()`) the display on one single line:

```r
library(flextable)

as.data.frame(matrix(rep("value [value1 - value2]", 20), ncol = 10)) %>% 
  flextable()%>% theme_box() %>% autofit()
```

This will produce a table display in an HTML window, this window has a width that is limited (the size of your window or the max-width of your HTML page). If the width of the browser window is less than the width of the table, it will be compressed to fit the window or the available space.

If you need to make this flextable horizontally scrollable (it is already implemented for bookdown but not yet for all HTML format), you can add this CSS code to your r markdown so that flextables can be scrollable (soon integrated into flextable then soon not necessary):

````
```{css echo=FALSE}
.flextable-shadow-host{
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```
````

An HTML 'R Markdown' document with it:

````
---
output: html_document
---


```{css echo=FALSE}
.flextable-shadow-host{
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```{r}
library(flextable)

as.data.frame(matrix(rep("value [value1 - value2]", 20), ncol = 10)) |> 
  flextable()|> theme_box() |> autofit()
```
````

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! A question now for large tables: can we then block the first row and the first column to facilitate reading?

Comment: as with excel? I don't think it is possible, this is static HTML

Comment: The function `scroll_box` from kableExtra has this feature

Comment: Ah ok. I just tried `scroll_box()` and did not see any way to fix the first column. How do you fix the first column with it?

Comment: You are right, the function freezes the first line. It's not enough but it's already something. Is it possible to freeze the first row with flextable?

Comment: Sure. I will add it in the next development run.

Comment: @DavidGohel I've just come across this question (and your solution) which is similar to a question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77480395/flextable-width-for-rmarkdown-html-document) but is slightly different as I don't want the width fixed to a standard autofit width but a custom one, would you be able to have a look please? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the huxtable equivalent:

```r
as_hux(table) |>  
  set_width(1) |> 
  set_wrap(FALSE) |>
  set_col_width("3.5cm") |> 
  quick_html()
```

which makes the table as wide as you want:

[image: HTML output]